# Show or hide certain menu in Yii header file

Tags: php, html, yii

I want to make my website menu appear with the following conditions:

1. If user did not login, the menu will be like this:

   > Gallery | Contact Us | Login
2. If the user logged into the website, the menu will appear like this:

   > Gallery | Contact Us | Logout

This is my coding to call menu in header file:

```
<?php
    $output = '';
    $menus1 = MenuPortal::model()->findAll(array('condition' => "type='atas' AND display_status='1' AND parent_id=0 ORDER BY sort ASC"));

    foreach ($menus1 as $menu) {
        $submenu = MenuPortal::model()->findAll(array('condition' => "parent_id=$menu->id"));
        if (sizeof($submenu) > 0) {
            foreach ($submenu as $smenu) {
                $output .= '<li><a href=' . $menu->url . '&id=' . PortalElement::encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $smenu->id) . '>' . $menu->title_my . '</a></li>';
                break;
            }
         }
         else {
             $output .= '<li><a href=' . $menu->url . '&id=' . PortalElement::encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $menu->id) . '>' . $menu->title_my . '</a></li>';
         }
   }

    echo $output;
?>
```

What I was thinking is to check if the session is active, then show menu #2. If there is no session, then show menu #1.

Comment: Code in screenshots is not searchable. Please [edit] it into your question.

Answer (score 2):

After Your `foreach` loop just apply following condition..

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest()){
  $output. = "<li><a href='login'>Login</a></li>";
}else{
  $output. = "<li><a href='login'>Logout</a></li>";
}
```